# CSS - 2 Column Layout - ASP .NET MVC3/Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to use some basic CSS to show a header, nav, column 1 (main), column 2 (sidebar), and footer.  I'm able to view this but I'm having trouble changing any of the colors.  I changed everything to Blue except the footer.  Have I removed something that's necessary for MVC3 and Razor?  I noticed earlier that if I didn't have my images beneath Content, then they wouldn't display.

Here's the **CSS**:

```
body, html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:Blue;
    background:Blue;
}

#wrap {
    width:750px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color: Blue;
    background:Blue;
}

#header {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:Blue;
}

h1 {
    margin:0;
}

#nav {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:Blue;
}

#main {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    color:Blue;
    background:Blue;
}

h2 {
    margin:0 0 1em;
}

#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:410px;
    padding:10px;
    color:Blue;
    background:Blue;
}

#footer {
    clear:both;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#ddd;
}

#footer p {
    margin:0;
    height: 1px;
}

#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

#nav li {
    display:list-item;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: please share a fiddle

Comment: Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jmacattack/4L2s5/

Answer (score 0):

You are using **same color** (Blue) for both `background` and `color` property. Because both the texts and backgrounds are having a same color you can't see anything, but the contents are there actually.

Change the `color: Blue;` to `color: #fff;` for `body`, `html`, `#wrap`, `#sidebar` etc.

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yawivixi/1/edit?html,css,output)** here.

Comment: I changed it to 'Blue' everywhere and it didn't update my web page.  I still have various colors in each section.  I'm not sure why the changes aren't updating when running in debug.  I've never run into this problem.  This is why I mentioned the 'images' above and how they needed to be beneath 'Contents' in this MVC3/Razor project.